# web config settings for a MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

Ive been looking at mvc authorization and have read how i shouldn't be using settings in my web config and i should be using the authorise attributes.

I have the auth settings in my global class and want to use the AllowAnnonymous function for my public controller.

But im getting credential prompts when testing, which im guessing is to do with my web config file.

currently my web config is as below

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

What do i need to change these settings to, to get these right?

Thanks

EDIT: Auth Code

when i access homecontroller i get 401 and this has no alloyanon (which is how i want)
when i access public controller i also get 401 which has alloyanon

IIS Settings
anon enabled
.net imper disabled
windows auth disabled
everything else disabled

global.asx

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
        }
```

authorise.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ITAPP.Helpers
{
    public class authorize
    {
    }
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {

            var isAuthorised = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

            if (isAuthorised)
            {
                // retrieve authentication ticket from cookie and
                // create custome principal and attach to 
                // httpContext.User
            }

            return isAuthorised;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {  
        Roles = @"DOMAIN\Network.Admin"; //Roles is AuthorizeAttribute member
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

publiccontroller.cs

```
namespace ITAPP.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class PublicController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Or your IIS is configured to require auth... (If you tell me which version of IIS you're running i can tell you how to check).

Comment: Start->run `compmgmt.msc`. Services & Applications->Internet Information Server. Authentication icon. Check for Anonymous Authentication=Enabled.

Comment: its currently set to .net and windows, do i disabled them and enaable anon?

Comment: i enabled anon and disabled the others, and couldnt load any page (permissions denied) then enabled them all and got the prompts again

Comment: enable anon on IIS, disable rest, then remove `Authentication Mode="Windows"`. that will allow anyone to visit the site and you can use SimpleMembership (or whatever) to authenticate your users as well as the `AuthorizeAttribute` to control access.

Comment: im getting 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: Just to check, when you say you have it set to AllowAnnonymous, you are using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute like so:  `[AllowAnonymous] public class XController : Controller` right?

Comment: ive added all the code i used and current settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sorted it with this setup in webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

and in iis:

```
anon: enabled
.net imper: enabled
windows auth: enabled
```